# Coda Slider stop on vimeo and youtube videos playback

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, slider, vimeo

I am using the Coda Slider [link](http://kevinbatdorf.github.com/codaslider/) to show the latest posts of embedded youtube and vimeo videos, but the slider continues on sliding when you press play on a video, how can i make the slider stop when a uses plays a video on the home page?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need a way of detecting when someone hits play, so that you may tell Coda to stop?

Comment: yes for youtube and vimeo.